# Plugins rewrite rules the right way

Tags: hooks, performance, rewrite-rules, init

I need to create rewrite rules for my plugin. This plugin will be running on a very large WordPress Network (+2000 sites) so performance is important.

Most tutorials and the codex recommend to `flush_rewrite_rule` on plugin activation and then to `add_rewrite_rule()` on `init`. But since rewrite rules are stored in DB it seems to me that we are wasting resources running `add_rewrite_rule` on every `init` (=every page load).

On the other hand you can't only rely on the plugin activation hook because if another plugin flush the rules then your rewrite rules would be lost.

I know that `add_rewrite_rule` is just some simple string and array manipulation and is not SUPER expensive in term of resources but it still feel not right....

Am I missing something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The add_rewrite_rule function doesn't change the database. Just an array in memory. It is not an expensive operation.

The alternative is to add code to detect whether your rule is there, which is actually more expensive than just modifying the array.

Comment: Thanks Otto, I'm taking over another developer on this plugin. I assumed add_rewrite_rule was writing to the DB because the plugin's rewrite rules are appearing in the "rewrite option" in the wp_options table. I wonder how my predecessor achieved  that then...I'll look into it on Monday.